# VBA to copy a range from XL and paste "Keep Text Only" in PPT

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint, paste

I have a range of cells with strings that I'd like to copy and paste into a pre-formatted text that's named in PPT. I'd like to paste it as "Keep Text Only" I know I can do it manually, but for the life of me I can't find any way to do it through VBA.

Here's a snippet of code:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & startRow & ":A" & endRow).Copy
oPPTApp.ActivePresentation.Slides(17).Shapes("ShapeName").TextFrame.TextRange.PasteSpecial DataType:=ppPasteText
```

I keep getting an error with this code:
Run-time error '-2147024809 (80070057)':
The specified value is out of range

I've checked the clipboard and the data is most definitely there. When I step through the code and stop before the error, I can see that I can paste it manually in PPT as "Keep Text Only".

Is there no other way but to loop string by string through my range?

Edit: I have reviewed the potential duplicate post but it still hasn't fixed the problem after checking that the text box has a text frame first. It's as if past special keep text only doesnt work when it's a range of cells?

Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find text in PowerPoint and Replace with text from a cell in excel using VBA, but keep getting Run-time error '-2147024809 (80070057)'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55940573/find-text-in-powerpoint-and-replace-with-text-from-a-cell-in-excel-using-vba-bu)

Comment: Thanks Ken - I hadn't come across that post, but after reading through it and trying to check if it has a text frame first, it's still not working. It's as if the .TextRange doesn't support PasteSpecial.

ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("OpenEndCharting").Range("A" & startRow & ":A" & endRow).Copy

If oPPTApp.ActivePresentation.Slides(17).Shapes("Column1").HasTextFrame Then
            oPPTApp.ActivePresentation.Slides(17).Shapes("Column1").TextFrame.TextRange.PasteSpecial DataType:=ppPasteText

End If

Comment: Copy and Paste operations frquently run into timing problems in VBA. It's possible that the Copy operation has not completed when the Paste is called. The clue is that when stepping through it operates as it's supposed to. Look into Wait, Sleep or looping DoEvents to solve this.

Comment: Thanks John - that didn't seem to help either :( I added a 10 second wait after copying and it's still failing on the PasteSpecial line. I've even tried selecting pre-exisitng text in the PPT text box to ensure that I was pasting over that and still it doesn't work.